# using UNIX Pipeline with C

Tags: c, unix

I am required to create 6 threads to perform a task (increment/decrement a number) concurrently until the integer becomes 0. I am supposed to be using only UNIX commands (Pipelines to be specific) and I can't get my head around how pipelines work, or how I can implement this program.

This integer *can* be stored in a text file.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can explain how to implement this program

Comment: It wasn't clear to me if you are referring to bash script or an actual  C program to do the job.

Comment: no not homework @anthony , I've been reading up on Operating Systems' book and it suggested that UNIX PIPEs can be used to protect Critical Sections of couple of processes running

Comment: So it's self assigned homework :-) @anthony do we still tag as `[homework]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is right, pipes can be used to protect critical sections, although how to do so is non-obvous.

```
int *make_pipe_semaphore(int initial_count)
{
   int *ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
   if (pipe(ptr)) {
       free(ptr);
       return NULL;
   }
   while (initial_count--) 
       pipe_release(ptr);
   return ptr;
}

void free_pipe_semaphore(int *sem)
{
    close(sem[0]);
    close(sem[1]);
    free(sem);
}

void pipe_wait(int *sem)
{
    char x;
    read(sem[0], &x, 1);
}

void pipe_release(int *sem)
{
   char x;
    write(sem[1], &x, 1);
}
```

The maximum free resources in the semaphore varies from OS to OS but is usually at least 4096. This doesn't matter for protecting a critical section where the initial and maximum values are both 1.

Usage:

```
/* Initialization section */
int *sem = make_pipe_semaphore(1);



/* critical worker */
{
    pipe_wait(sem);
    /* do work */

    /* end critical section */
    pipe_release(sem);
}
```